# Weird Javascript Issue keeping some variables undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

When the following function is ran in my browser, the deleted variable, the row variable and the rownumber variable remain undefined throughout the execution of the function:

```
    private action(value) {
        var deleted = false;            
        if (value == 3) {
            for (var row in this.binaryObj) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.binaryObj[row].length; i++) {
                    if (deleted) {
                        break;
                    }                       
                    this.binaryObj[row].sort();
                    if (this.binaryObj[row][i] + this.binaryObj[row][i + 1] === value) {                                
                        var rowNumber = $.inArray(this.binaryObj[row][i], this.binaryObj[row])
                        this.cleanField(rowNumber, value);
                        deleted = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (deleted) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var row in this.binaryObj) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.binaryObj[row].length && !deleted; i++) {
                    if (this.binaryObj[row][i] === value) {
                        var rowNumber = $.inArray(this.binaryObj[row][i], this.binaryObj[row])
                        this.cleanField(rowNumber, value);
                        deleted = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (deleted) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
    };
```

I'm not sure why this could be happening. the deleted variable is clearly declared at the start of the function. Anyone who knows what could be an issue?
Note that the function is part of a typescript file and as you can see I'm also using JQuery (not sure if one of those things could be the issue?)

this.binaryObj IS actually noticed by the debugger as:
`Object {R1: Array[0], R2: Array[2], R3: Array[2], R4: Array[3]}`

Comment: What does this do? `console.lo(this.binaryObj)`

Comment: @AdrianLynch lol it'll do this: `Uncaught TypeError: console.lo is not a function`

Comment: if I type in the object (this.binaryObj), it returns the object.
If I do console.log(this.binarObj), it returns undefined -_-

Comment: that a typo? `this.binarObj` not same as `this.binaryObj`. How are you testing the value of `deleted`?

Comment: omfg now deleted works (without code changes), but row and rownumber remain undefined, and the "i" iterator is undefined now :(.... I guess this does not seem to be a code issue

Comment: And before it was a typo, console.log(this.binaryObj) returns the same object as it does if you type this.binaryObj

Comment: I think I know what the problem is!. 
Logging this.binaryObj returns the object as I said but when I log:
`for (var row in this.binaryObj) { console.log(row)}`, it returns:
R1
R2
R3
R4
undefined

The item binaryObj looks like:
Object {R1: Array[0], R2: Array[2], R3: Array[2], R4: Array[3]}
R1: Array[0]
R2: Array[2]
R3: Array[2]
R4: Array[3]
__proto__: Object